# Change attr width on object

Tags: object

How to change `attr` width on object, I'm trying with this, but seems does not work...

```
jQuery('.big').click(function(){
    jQuery('#flvPlayer').attr("width", "100");
});
```

Here is code where I need change height and width on click

```
<a class="big">100</a>
<textarea><object id="flvPlayer" height="665" width="425"></object></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.css` instead of `.attr`.

```
jQuery('.big').click(function(){
    jQuery('#flvPlayer').css("width", "100");
});
```

`width` is a CSS property.

Edit: In `textarea` you have text. Your `<object>` is not a HTML element. It is text in your text area.

So, just change the text in `textarea`.

```
$('.big').click(function(){
    var text = "<object id=\"flvPlayer\" height=\"665\" width=\"100\"></object>"
    $("textarea").val(text);
});
```

Also, I suggest you to use `$` instead of `jQuery`. It's easier and faster to write.